# Samsung C6112 (J2ME handset) InterruptedIOException issue

Tags: iis, java-me, https, ioexception, samsung-mobile

On Samsung C6112 handset, m facing weird  problems.

My midlet application is trying to connect to HTTPS url. (Its Hosted on IIS 6.0 Web Server with Versign certificate).

i am sending data using POST method. After finished with writing post data, i call **outputstream.flush()** and  **outputstream.close()** method. These two method gives "**InterruptedIOException** or **IOException:TCP open**" .

if i comment both methods i.e. .flush() and .close(), hc.openInputStream(); throws same exception.

Following sample code, please suggest me if there is something wrong.

```
    InputStream is = null;
OutputStream dos = null;
HttpConnection hc = null;
try {
        hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE,true);

        byte b1[] = "Hello_World".getBytes();

        hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

        dos = hc.openOutputStream();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < b1.length) {
            dos.write(b1[i]);
            i++;
        }
        dos.write("\r\n".getBytes());

        dos.flush(); // gives **InterruptedIOException** or **IOException:TCP open**
        dos.close(); // gives **InterruptedIOException** or **IOException:TCP open**

        is = hc.openInputStream();

        byte b[];
        ByteArrayOutputStream bStrm = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int ch, downloadedData=0;
        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
            downloadedData++;
            bStrm.write(ch);
        }
        b = bStrm.toByteArray();

    } catch (javax.microedition.pki.CertificateException ce) {
      System.out.println("CertificateException in " + ce.toString());
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
      System.out.println("SecurityException: ", se.toString());
    } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException cnfe) {
      System.out.println("ConnectionNotFoundException: ", cnfe.toString());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println("IOException: ", ioe.toString() + ioe.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception: ", e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (hc != null) {
            try {
                hc.close();
                hc = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("finally hc.close(); IOException " + e.getMessage() + "  " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        if(is !=null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("finally is.close(); Exception " + e.getMessage() + "  " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know how to deal with Samsung j2me phones.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

instead of,

```
dos = hc.openOutputStream();
```

try this,

```
dos = (OutputStream) hc.openOutputStream();
```

and instead of,

```
is = hc.openInputStream();
```

try this,

```
is = (InputStream) hc.openInputStream();
```

However I would like to suggest you to use `DataInputStream` & `DataOutputStream` class for these operations.

Comment: Hey Lucifer, thank u for replying. I have tried ur solution but still giving "InterruptedIOexception".

Comment: yes , you need to write .getResponseCode() after the is = hc.openInputStream() line.

Comment: okies, can you please comment your these lines dos.flush(); & dos.close(); and now run the program.

Comment: Got iterruptedIOException error on is = hc.openInputStream(); line